# Angular : header search form does not load multiple times

Tags: angular, forms, search, parameter-passing

I have header search icon which shows small popup of input and button on click. If user searches for any input then I am redirecting user to results page. I have separate component for header and search results. I am passing search input with common service from header to search result.

This works fine for first time. When I enter new text and search then nothing happens. It does not pass search input to search result component and also does not load search result again.

**header template html**

```
  <a
          #closeSearchForm
            href="#"
            data-title="Search"
            class=""
            id="dropdownMenuButton1"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false"
            ><img src="assets/images/icons/search.png" alt=""
          /></a>
          <span class="tooltiptext">Search</span>
          <div
            class="member_login search_menu_dropdown dropdown-menu"
            aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1"
          >
            <form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitSearch()"> 
              
              <div class="search_menu_wrap">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input
                  
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Search here...."
                    formControlName="searchInput"
                    [ngClass]="{ error_border: submitted1 && sf.searchInput.errors }"
                  />
                  <div *ngIf="submitted1 && sf.searchInput.errors" class="text-danger">
                    <div *ngIf="sf.searchInput.errors.required">Search text is required</div>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn" type="submit">
                  Search</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

**header ts code**

```
 onSubmitSearch() {
    this.submitted1 = true;
    if (this.searchForm.invalid) {
      this.loading1 = false;
      return;
    }

    this.loading1 = true;
    if (this.sf.searchInput.value) {
      this.closeSearchForm.nativeElement.click();
      var searchValue = this.sf.searchInput.value;
      //   this.searchForm.reset();

      // Object.keys(this.searchForm.controls).forEach(key => {
      //   this.searchForm.get(key).setErrors(null) ;
      // });
      this.commonModelService.data = searchValue;
      this.router.navigate(['search-results']);
    }
  }
```

**common model service code - for passing search input**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CommonModelService{
  data:any
}
```

**search result component ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this.searchValue = this.commonModelService.data;
    this.getSearchResults();  <!-- this function will call api and show data in html -->
  }
```

I am not getting what is going wrong. Right now its working only for first time. Search should work any time with any input given by user.

What will be the best solution to pass search input from header component to search component and achieve search functionality working any time , on any page, with any new inputs when user tries to search?

Please help and guide. Thanks

Comment: On the second time, Is your search form on `search-result` route? Or you are trying to navigate from different route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already on the search result, you redirect code will not re-render the component and without re-render your `search.result.component-> ngOninit` will not fire and load the result.

Instead of passing data directly you should your observable and Behaviour subject.

search result component ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.commonModelService.search$.subscribe((searchInput) => {
 if(searchInput !=== undefined){ // we want to capture empty string
 this.getSearchResults()
 }
})
 
  }
```

common model service code - for passing search input

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

public search$ = new BehaviorSubject(undefined) // if undefined initially we don't do anything.
@Injectable()
export class CommonModelService{
  data:any
}
```

BehavourSubect will return the last event value when its subscribe the first time and in subsequent case, when you are already at the page it will push value like regular subject.
Advice: also remove the subscribe every time on OnDistory

```
this.commonModelService.search.next(searchValue);
  this.router.navigate(['search-results']);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.